# HighchartsJS getting data from URL and pass it to series data

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, highcharts

i have difficulty in setting data from URL. Basically, the data gets from a URL and then will be passed to Highcharts function.

When i try to log with  `console.log(data)` it does not display any data in it. I'm using Laravel to get the data in route and "Column with rotated labels" as charts. Below is my codes:

Graph:

```
<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

This is a data string, inside /komputer/chart:

```
[['Shanghai', 23.7],['Florida',3],['Dubai', 1]]
```

Ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
    url: '{!! url("komputer/chart") !!}',
    type: 'GET',
    async: true,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (data) {
    console.log(data); //display: [['Shanghai', 23.7],['PTJ1',3],['vbnvbn', 1]]
    $('#container').highcharts({
        console.log(data) //doesn't display anything
        chart: {type: 'column'},
        title: {text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'},
        subtitle: {text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'},
        legend: {enabled: false},
        tooltip: {pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'},
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {rotation: -45,style: {fontSize: '13px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'}},
            title: {text: 'Cities'}
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {text:'Population (millions)'}
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Population',
            data: data,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                format: '{point.y:.1f}', 
                y: 10,
                style: {fontSize: '13px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'}
            }
        }]
    });  
    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: wait, did you realize `console.log(data) //doesn't display anything` is inside an object? it'd be invalid as far as i know. but i wonder if your browser console rant about it or not. so far, your code roughly resemble [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236113/creating-highchart-with-ajax-json-data). perhaps you could use it as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I complete it by looking at this tutorial,

http://www.knowstack.com/different-ways-of-loading-highcharts-data/

Ajax script:

```
 $(function() {

var processed_json = new Array();     

$.getJSON('{!! url("komputer/chart") !!}', function(data) {
    for(var key in data){
        processed_json.push(new Array(data[key].key, data[key].value));
    }

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {type: 'column'},
        title: {text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'},
        subtitle: {text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'},
        legend: {enabled: false},
        tooltip: {pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'},
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {rotation: -45,style: {fontSize: '13px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'}},
            title: {text: 'Cities'}
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {text:'Population (millions)'}
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Population',
            data: processed_json,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                format: '{point.y:.1f}', 
                y: 10,
                style: {fontSize: '13px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'}
            }
        }]
    });  
});
```

});

JSON data, not in string, the data is still not complete yet:

```
{"3":{"key":"PTJ1","value":3},"6":{"key":"vbnvbn","value":1}}
```

Comment: @SebastianBochan, sorry for late reply, yeah by looking at the tutorial, i'm able to solve it