# Update highstock chart dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I am still learning to use Highchart to create a chart with data from MySQL. I have managed to make a chart using Highstock (highchart). Then, I want the chart to update the data without reloading the page. How can the chart update data (plotting points), without reloading the page ? . My question is, how to add point from PHP without reloading the web page ?

My chart

[image]

Javascript code :

```js
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('stockTemp.php', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('stockTemp', {
      rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
          type: 'hour',
          count: 1,
          text: '1H'
        }, {
          type: 'hour',
          count: 24,
          text: '24H'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 7,
          text: '7D'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 1,
          text: '1M'
        }, {
          type: 'all',
          count: 1,
          text: 'All'
        }],
        selected: 1,
        inputEnabled: true
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature'
      },
      yAxis: {
        opposite: false,

        title: {
          text: 'Temperature',
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return this.value + '°C';
          }
        }

      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Suhu',
        data: data,
        marker: {
          enabled: true,
          radius: 6,
          symbol: 'diamond'
        },

        shadow: true,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

PHP code :

```
<?php 

include("connection.php");

$data = array();
$count = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi,"SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY time ASC ") or die ("Connection error");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
  $x = strtotime($row['time']) * 1000; 
$y =    (float)$row['temperature'];
$data[] = array($x, $y);
$count++;
}
echo json_encode($data);
mysqli_close($koneksi);
?>
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Checkout this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236113/creating-highchart-with-ajax-json-data) which shows how to use ajax to load data dynamically with highcharts

Comment: Possible duplicate of [creating highchart with ajax json data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236113/creating-highchart-with-ajax-json-data)

Comment: You have two options, and choose one of them depending on the way of updating data. If you need to try update entire data, use `Series.setData()` function. If you would like to add new point to your series, just use `Series.addPoint`. You can read more about the `Series` prototype functions in the documentation: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series

Comment: @daniel_s can you explain how to use it in my code ? Sorry, I'm not good at using highcharts or javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded that would be better to post the separate answer in this topic.
In order to achieve expected effect, you need to create the `setInterval` function inside of  the `chart.events.load` event handler, and in that interval just call `$.getJSON('stockTemp.php', function() ...` which would do the `setData()` on the series passing the data you've got when `getJSON` succeed. I know, sounds creepy, butit should look similar to that:

```
$(function() {
  $.getJSON('stockTemp.php', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    Highcharts.stockChart('stockTemp', {
      chart: {
        events: {
          load: function() {
            var chart = this
            setInterval(function() {
              $.getJSON('stockTemp.php', function(newData) {
                chart.series[0].setData(newData)
              }
            }, 5000) // Update the chart every 5 seconds
          }
        }
      },
      rangeSelector: {
        buttons: [{
          type: 'hour',
          count: 1,
          text: '1H'
        }, {
          type: 'hour',
          count: 24,
          text: '24H'
        }, {
          type: 'day',
          count: 7,
          text: '7D'
        }, {
          type: 'month',
          count: 1,
          text: '1M'
        }, {
          type: 'all',
          count: 1,
          text: 'All'
        }],
        selected: 1,
        inputEnabled: true
      },
      title: {
        text: 'Temperature'
      },
      yAxis: {
        opposite: false,

        title: {
          text: 'Temperature',
        },
        labels: {
          formatter: function() {
            return this.value + '°C';
          }
        }

      },
      series: [{
        name: 'Suhu',
        data: data,
        marker: {
          enabled: true,
          radius: 6,
          symbol: 'diamond'
        },

        shadow: true,
        tooltip: {
          valueDecimals: 2
        }
      }]
    });
  });
});
```

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/chart.events.load

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#setData