# how to pass data into bar Highchart using ajax in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, highcharts

i already passed data into bar highchart using php and it's work. but when i load the page it takes around **5 sec**(That's long enough). and after i did some research i found many forums recommended using ajax for Highchart. so i'm just guessing maybe using ajax can make page load faster(correct me if im wrong).

**But the problem is**, i don't know how to use ajax for Bar highchart . could anyone help me and give me some clue how to start use ajax for passing data from Controller to ajax?

here is my current code:

MODEL :

```
 public function isiChart()
 {
$query = $this->db->query('select KODE_BRG,NAMA_BRG,COUNT(case when total=3 then 1 else null end) OOS,
                            COUNT(case when total >=1 and total <= 3 then 1 else null end) kurang_4,
                            COUNT(case when total>3 then 1 else null end)  OSA from 
                            (select  b.KODE_BRG,d.NAMA_BRG,b.JUM_KARTON,b.JUM_SATUAN,b.JUM_KARTON*d.FRACT+b.JUM_SATUAN  total
                            from assrkmd a 
                            left join assrkmdstok b on b.TGL_RKM=a.TGL_RKM and b.KODE_MDS=a.KODE_MDS and b.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
                            left join asscus c on c.KODE_CUS=a.KODE_CUS
                            inner join asstok d on d.KODE_BRG=b.KODE_BRG
                            left join asssup e on e.KODE_SPL=d.KODE_SPL
                            left join asssgrup f on f.KODE_SGRUP=c.KODE_SGRUP
                            left join assgrup g on g.KODE_GRUP=f.KODE_GRUP
                            inner join assmds h on h.KODE_MDS=a.KODE_MDS
                            left join asssgrupbrg i on i.KODE_SGRUP=d.KODE_SGRUP
                            left join assgrupbrg j on j.KODE_GRUP=i.KODE_GRUP 
                            inner join assgrupmds k on k.KODE_GROUP=h.KODE_GROUP
                            where h.TIPE_MDS =0 and a.CHECK_OUT is not null ) g 
                            group by KODE_BRG,NAMA_BRG order by NAMA_BRG');
                            return $query;
```

CONTROLLER :

```
public function index()
{

    $data['db1'] = $this->m_mds->isiChart();

    $data['content'] = 'tempelates/MDS/content';
    $data['chart'] = 'tempelates/MDS/chart';
    $this->load->view('tempelate',$data);
}
```

VIEW :

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12">
 <div class="x_panel">                  
 <div class="x_title">
  <h2>Bar graph <small>Sessions</small></h2>
  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
    <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="x_content">
<div id="container" style="overflow-x: auto;"></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/vendors/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/accessibility.js"></script>
<?php foreach ($db1->result_array() as $key) { <---! Here i foreach data comes from Controller--->
  $data[]= $key['NAMA_BRG'];
  $data0[]=$key['OOS'];
  $data1[]= $key['kurang_4'];
  $data2[]=$key['OSA'];
}?>
<script>
 Highcharts.chart('container', {
 chart: {type: 'bar',options3d: { enabled: true, }},
 title: {text: 'All Product vs Call'},
 xAxis: {
   categories: [<?php echo '"'.join('","',$data).'"';?> ],
   title: {text: null},
   min: 0,max: 8,
   scrollbar: {enabled: true},
   tickLength: 0},
   yAxis: {title: {text: ''}},
   legend: {reversed: true},
   plotOptions: {series: {stacking: 'normal'}},
   credits: {enabled: true},
   exporting: { enabled: true },
   dataSorting: { enabled: true},
   series: [{
   name: 'OOS',
   data: [<?php echo join(',',$data0);?>],
   color: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
   borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
   dataLabels: {enabled: true,
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    align: 'center',
    format: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{point.percentage:.1f} %',
    y: 1, // 10 pixels down from the top
   style: {
     fontSize: '10px',
     fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
    }
   }
  },{
   name: '<4',
   data: [<?php echo join(',',$data1);?>],
 color: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.3)',
 borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
 dataLabels: {
   enabled: true,color: '#FFFFFF',align: 'center',
   format: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{point.percentage:.1f} %',
   y: 1, // 10 pixels down from the top
   style: { fontSize: '10px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'}
 }
 },{
  name: 'OSA',
  data: [<?php echo join(',',$data2);?>],
  color: 'rgb(51, 255, 153, 0.6)',
  borderColor: 'rgb(51, 255, 153)',
   dataLabels:{
    enabled: true,
    color: '#FFFFFF',
    align: 'center',
    format: '<b>{point.name}</b><br>{point.percentage:.1f} %',
    // format: '{point.y:.1f}', // one decimal
    y: 1, // 10 pixels down from the top
    style: {fontSize: '10px',fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'}
  }
 }]
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: I think that your question is related to generally fetching the data through the AJAX call than using the Highcharts library, which means that this Highcharts tag is not needed here. Also, I think that related questions were asked many times: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236113/creating-highchart-with-ajax-json-data

Comment: thnak you for ur reply . i really  appreciate it .. and sorry for that is my bad .. i'm just confuse how to implement it in my case n need some guidance .. thnx again n i will try the link that u sent to me :) @SebastianWędzel